# Sizing large but not small images to fit on a html table

Tags: html, css

I have a table which can contain images which can be bigger than a table cell. What I have done is truncate the images so that they don't expand the table (using table-layout: fixed).

http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/wy0skbmn/

What I would like to do is size the image so that it fits on the table. I have commented this out in my fiddle:

```
img.imgcode {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

this works fine for a large image like in my example, but in the case the image is smaller than the td it increases the size of the image.

What I want is to resize the image, but only if it is not too large. If it fits already I don't want to resize it. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `max-width: 100%;` instead of `width: 100%;`?

Comment: I thought I had tried that but it does seem to work in this small example: http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/wjp1mj90/1/, I will revisit my actual code base thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
img.imgcode {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```